# Asymptotic theta notation leads to a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I have came across this picture right here:
[image]

and I do not understand how come $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{g\left(n\right)}{f\left(n\right)}=c>0$$
I tried to prove it and noticed a seemingly counter example.
We know that:
$$1\cdot 8\le \sin\left(x\right)+10\le 12\cdot 1$$
So $$\sin (x)=Θ \left(1\right)$$
but $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sin\left(x\right)+10}{1}\right)$$
diverges.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(x)=\Theta(1)$?

Comment: yes exactly. changed.

Comment: Are you sure $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sin(x) + 10)$ converges? Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it diverges. Does it contradict that picture?

Comment: The picture deals only with the cases where the limit exists. It doesn't handle more general cases like yours.

Comment: Daniel Fischer can you send me a link to a proof?